# Закрывается клиент.Socket (C#)

Tags: c#, сервер, tcp

Начал изучать Socket.Нашел на просторах интернета реализацию сервер-клиент
Скажите почему окно клиента закрывается  после отправки 1 строки на сервер и попытки ввести 2 строку.

КОД СЕРВЕРА

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SocketTcpServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static int port = 8888; // порт для приема входящих запросов
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // получаем адреса для запуска сокета
            IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);

            // создаем сокет
            Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                // связываем сокет с локальной точкой, по которой будем принимать данные
                listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);

                // начинаем прослушивание
                listenSocket.Listen(10);

                Console.WriteLine("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений...");

                while (true)
                {
                    Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();
                    // получаем сообщение
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0; // количество полученных байтов
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024]; // буфер для получаемых данных

                    do
                    {
                        bytes = handler.Receive(data);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (handler.Available > 0);

                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " + builder.ToString());

                    // отправляем ответ
                    string message = "ваше сообщение доставлено";
                    data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                    handler.Send(data);
                    // закрываем сокет
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

КОД КЛИЕНТА

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SocketTcpClient
{
    class Program
    {
        // адрес и порт сервера, к которому будем подключаться
        static int port = 8888; // порт сервера
        static string address = "127.0.0.1"; // адрес сервера
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), port);

                Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                // подключаемся к удаленному хосту
                socket.Connect(ipPoint);
                Console.Write("Введите сообщение:");
                string message = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                socket.Send(data);

                // получаем ответ
                data = new byte[256]; // буфер для ответа
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0; // количество полученных байт

                do
                {
                    bytes = socket.Receive(data, data.Length, 0);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (socket.Available > 0);
                Console.WriteLine("ответ сервера: " + builder.ToString());

                // закрываем сокет
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Пытался разобратся но так и не понял в чем дело.
Я так и непонял почему

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но вроде бы, после закрытия сокета, заново установить подключения на том же объекте сокета (без создания нового объекта оператором new) нельзя. Пройдитесь под отладчиком по серверу и по клиенту, выясните где ошибка или в любом случае Вы лучше поймете как он работает.

Comment: А, собственно, где у вас в коде есть попытка ввода второй строки?

Comment: В цикле while(true){}

Comment: while (true)
                {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    socket.Connect(ipPoint);
                    Console.Write("Введите сообщение:");
                    string message = Console.ReadLine();
                    byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                    socket.Send(data);} сделал так  вроде ок стало